# Excel VBA - jump the cell to next change in the column

Tags: vba, excel-formula

Hello I have a worksheet (named "Sheet1") with data in Column B (beginning on B1) .
I'd also like to jump the cell to next change in the column like in the picture  at given url:-

https://ibb.co/xqR8CyH

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Dim row as Integer, prevVal as Variant
row = 1
While row <= 10 'Arbitrary limit, change this condition if you want to check a different number of rows.
    If Sheet1.Cells(row,2) <> "" And Sheet1.Cells(row,2) <> prevVal Then 'Checks for a change in value
        'Perform your operation in here.
    End If
    'Updates prevVal to the current cell value if it's not blank.
    prevVal = IIf(Sheet1.Cells(row,2) <> "", Sheet1.Cells(row,2), prevVal)
    'Check the next row
    row = row + 1 
Wend
```

This VBA code can go in a `Sub` or `Function` of your choosing.